# How can I show the info on annotation without having to click on it?

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations

```
for (MyAnnotation *a in dealerMapView.annotations) {
    // Your current position (if shown) is an annotation as well. Thus check for the right class!
    if ([a isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {
        // insert some smart if statement here, if you have multiple annotations!
        [[dealerMapView viewForAnnotation:a] setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I used the code above code, but info is not displaying on pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.dealerMapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation2 animated:YES];
```

I used this statement and now its displaying the info on annotation.